# how to make first row of DataGrid ReadOnly in wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

i have a data from database in Datagrid and i want to edit all data without first row:

[image: Here you can see image by clicking this link]

I want to use only first row as a read-only and others I want to edit Jaama `Rs` and `BaNaam Amount`.

**Here is the code:**

```
                        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="463"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,43,0,0" 
                             x:Name="gridcustomer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="911" IsReadOnly="True" ColumnWidth="*">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding tblcustomer.Id}" Header="Code No" Width="60" 
                                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date}" Header="Date" 
                                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding tblcustomer.CustomerName}" Header="CustomerName"
                                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Jaama Rs">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox x:Name="txteditcustomergridjamma" PreviewKeyDown="txteditcustomergridjamma_PreviewKeyDown"  PreviewTextInput="txteditcustomergridjamma_PreviewTextInput" Text="{Binding Jaama}"      />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="BaNaam Rs">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox x:Name="txteditcustomergridbanaam" PreviewKeyDown="txteditcustomergridbanaam_PreviewKeyDown"  PreviewTextInput="txteditcustomergridbanaam_PreviewTextInput" Text="{Binding Banaam}"      />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Balence}" Header="Balence Rs" 
                                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BalenceHistory}" Header="BalenceHistory" 
                                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

> cs code is

```
gridcustomer.ItemsSource=db.customerledger.toList();
```

Comment: i just want readonly first row in datagrid

Comment: Add a column to the DataTable and set the value of this one for the first row. You can then use a RowStyle with a DataTrigger to disable the row container.

Comment: How to do this plz give me some helping material

Comment: Please share your current code and XAML markup if you want any further help.

Comment: i share the code please see this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `RowStyle` to disable the row where `Balence == 0`, for example:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="463"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,43,0,0" 
        x:Name="gridcustomer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="911" IsReadOnly="True" ColumnWidth="*">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Balence}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```